# Is there a way to combine the indexes inside a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I don't know if this is possible and so far I haven't found a way to do it. I have a list of lists that contain names. Some lists have 2 elements and others have 3 `[['Doe', 'John'], ['Doe', 'Jr.,', 'John']]`. Is there a way to combine the indexes inside a list of lists. I can do it with a single list, but I get an error saying `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found` when I try it on a list of lists. I was trying to do something like this:

```
while(len(name_list) > 2:
    indices = [0, 1]
    name_list = ['Doe', 'Jr.,', 'John']

    join_index = ' '.join([e for i, e in enumerate(name_list) if i in indices])
    print(join_index)
```

Comment: *"Is there a way to combine the indexes inside a list of lists."* - You're going to have to present a clearer problem statement than that.

Comment: From what I understand, there are two possibilities for what you might be doing. Firstly you may be trying to put the sublists together into a string: `['Doe John', 'Doe Jr. John']`. The other possibility is that you want to ensure that accessing `superlist[0][3]` will return a valid string so that you don't get `ValueError`. Please clarify what your intended result will look like, and perhaps explain *why* you need to do this.

Comment: I'm putting it all into a csv file. When it loads some of the names are in the wrong columns because of the extra index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final answer

```
length = (len(names))

j=0
while j < length:

    if len(names[j]) > 3:
        names[j][0] = ''.join((names[j][0], ' ', names[j][1]))
        del(names[j][1])
        #print(names[j])
        j += 1
    else:
        #print('3 or less')
        j += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

So it appears you are trying to combine the names to produce (last, first) from something more complex.

This code will combine all but the last element of the sub-list:

**Code:**

```
names = [['Doe', 'John'], ['Doe', 'Jr.,', 'John']]
print(names)

new_list = [[' '.join(n[:-1]), n[-1]] for n in names]
print(new_list)
```

**Results:**

```
[['Doe', 'John'], ['Doe', 'Jr.,', 'John']]

[['Doe', 'John'], ['Doe Jr.,', 'John']]
```